# Problems comparing two array lists objects

Tags: java, object, arraylist, instanceof

This may seem like a dumb question but I have been stuck on this for awhile. The code I have is supposed to check if two array lists are equal, even if they are out of order. 
boolean equals(Object other) Returns true if the given object is a LineSegmentDB that contains the same line segments as lineSegments. So far I have this code:

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
//      Object lineSegments2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
//      lineSegments2 = other;

        if (!(other instanceof LineSegmentDB)) {
            return false;
        }
        ArrayList otherTest = (ArrayList) other;


        if(other.size() != lineSegments.size()){
            return false;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < lineSegments.size(); i++){
            if(!(other.contains(lineSegments.get(i)))){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
        //return lineSegments2;

    }
```

I make sure that other is an instance of LineSegmentDB. Then I am pretty sure I have to create a instance variable for other, so I can use things like other.size() or other.get(i). I thought the code would be similar to some other code I wrote but but whatever i try doesn't work, any suggestions?

Other Code:

```
ArrayList<LineSegment> union(LineSegmentDB other){
        ArrayList<LineSegment> lineSegments2 = new ArrayList<LineSegment>();
        lineSegments2 = other.lineSegments;


        for(int i = 0; i < other.size(); i++){
            if(hasPoint(other.getSegment(i))){
                System.out.println("Has Duplicate");
            }else{
                lineSegments.add(other.getSegment(i));
            }
        }
        return lineSegments;


    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit, Not sure if this helps:

```
public class LineSegmentDB {
    public ArrayList<LineSegment> lineSegments = new ArrayList<LineSegment>();

    LineSegmentDB(){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LineSegmentDB db = new LineSegmentDB();
        LineSegmentDB db2 = new LineSegmentDB();

        db.addLineSegment(new LineSegment(2,2,4,2));
        db.addLineSegment(new LineSegment(3,3,1,3));
        db.addLineSegment(new LineSegment(4,2,4,10));
        db2.addLineSegment(new LineSegment(4,2,2,2));
        db2.addLineSegment(new LineSegment(4,2,4,10));
        db2.addLineSegment(new LineSegment(3,3,3,1));
        System.out.println(db.equals(db2));


    }
```

Also I know its uncool to paste a alot of code but maybe it might answer some questions that I cant.
http://pastebin.com/FUEsYA0n

Thanks again, you guys are seriously life savers.

Comment: Hello. What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Does your `equals` compile? Is `lineSegments` a class attribute?

Comment: The main problem is things like  other.size() and  other.contains()  are requiring me to cast it,((ArrayList<LineSegment>) other), which when i run throws an class cast exception.

Comment: I think when you reach `ArrayList otherTest = (ArrayList) other;`, `other` is a `LineSegmentDB` object, not an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Yeah i noticed that too, and changed it 'LineSegmentDB otherTest = (LineSegmentDB) other;' But it didnt seem to fix anything.

Comment: It looks like `LineSegmentDB` encapsulate a `List<LineSegment>` object, is that true?

Comment: Sorry i'm still trying to understand this stuff and its kinda new to me, would you mind elaborating a little?

Comment: LineSegmentDB is not extending the functionality of an ArrayList. It is internally using ArrayList to get something done. So, you cant type-cast and treat it as an ArrayList. You could have a getList method in LineSegmentDB and return the ArrayList. Then you can loop through the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more a guess than an answer, but..

In your first piece of code you check if `other` is of type `LineSegmentDb`, if it's true you cast `other` to type `ArrayList`. You get a `java.lang.ClassCastException` because other is of type `LineSegmentDb`, as you checked.
In your second piece of code this line, `other.lineSegments` make me guess that a `LineSegmentDb` object has a `List<LineSegment>` attribute. If it's so, try change

```
if(other.lineSegments.size() != lineSegments.size()){
    return false;
}

for(int i = 0; i < lineSegments.size(); i++){
    if(!(other.contains(lineSegments.get(i)))){
        return false;
    }
}
```

to

```
if(((LineSegmentDB)other).lineSegments.size() != lineSegments.size()) {
    return false;
}

for(int i = 0; i < lineSegments.size(); i++){
    if(!(((LineSegmentDB)other).lineSegments
        .contains(lineSegments.get(i)))){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This fixed it! That was the last thing i needed thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What is `LineSegmentDB`? Does it extend some `List` implementation or implement the `List` interface itself? I guess the answer is **no**.

Now to your `equals()` method:

```
if (!(other instanceof LineSegmentDB)) {
    return false;
}
```

This part is OK. You correctly check first if the given object is the same type as your instance.

```
ArrayList otherTest = (ArrayList) other;
if(other.size() != lineSegments.size()){
    return false;
}
```

I guess your `LineSegmentDB` is not a `List` at all. Your class must implement the `List` interface. This could be done by two ways:

- Implement the interface by itself - `implements List`
- Extend a class that has already implemented the interface - `extends ArrayList`

If one of the bullets above is true, you can safely cast your object to `List` and then use the `size()` or `contains()` methods.

Hope this was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Checking for set equality using lists can be inefficient if you don't use any other data structure.

If you had 2 lists, `listA` and `listB`, intuitive way to check if they have the same elements would be to iterate over non-marked items in `listB` for each element in `listA`. Provided they are of the same length, `n`, it's a quadratic time complexity.

Instead, you can use `HashMap` in Java. Here's a quick pseudo-code for your task:

```
// do proper null and size equality checks
Map<V, Integer> map = new HashMap<V, Integer>();
for (V v : listA) {
    int countSoFar = map.getOrDefault(v, 0);
    map.put(v, countSoFar + 1);
}

for (V v : listB) {
    int countSoFar = map.getOrDefault(v, 0);
    if (countSoFar == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    map.put(v, countSoFar - 1);
}

return checkIfAllValuesInMapEqualZero(map);
```

What this essentially does? It registers the occurrences of each element from the first list by increasing counter for each individual element. Then, it decreases the counter for each element that is in the second list.

If there are more elements of 1 type in `listB` than in `listA`, counter for that particular element will reach 0 before you've used them all in `listB`, which indicates that something is missing in `listA`, which indicates they are not the same.
In a similar fashion, `listA` may have more of each elements than `listB`. If that is the case, at lesat one of the entries in the map will have count > 0.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `instanceof` test will work only if `LineSegmentDB` extends `ArrayList`. (Or you have to correct the `instanceof` test)
2. `contains` method uses `equals` implementation of `LineSegment` to compare if two instances are functional equivalients. If you have not overridden `equals`, the `contains` check will compare only references.